# Rails - AJAX a Modal Dialog?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm interested in learning how to AJAX a modal dialog. Typically if I wanted to add a modal dialog to my web site I added the jquery UI dialog code in my main JS file and binded it to an ID.

I believe with Rails I can create a Link, which fetches all the dialog code from the server and then opens the dialog.

Is this true?

If so, can you help me understand by providing a simple example of where everything lives in the rails MVC world?

Thanks

Comment: The must is just use JqueryUI.dialog. You don't need some rails specific

Comment: What do you mean by "fetches all the dialog code from the server"? Do you mean fetch the jQuery code which can create the dialog? Why wouldn't you just have this code in a js file which is included in your layout or view? If you're trying to retrieve something with which to populate the dialog, that's a different story.

Comment: Hmm, is there more to the question that I didn't answer below? If acceptable, I would appreciate an accept of the answer :)

Answer (score 37):

Gosh, you asked this 4 months ago so you've probably figured this out by now. I also had trouble finding a good write up on how to do this. Here's what I figured out:

In whatever page you want to pull up this dialog box, you want to have a div like so (notice you don't want to display this yet):

```
<div id="person-form" title="Person" style="display:none"></div>
```

In that view, you also want an Ajax call to pull up this dialog box:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_person_path(person), :remote => true %>
```

Obviously, you want this edit_person_path to route to some action. That action should render a js.erb that has something like the following (in jQuery):

```
$("#person-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 600,
  width: 600,
  modal: true,
  title: 'Edit Person',
  buttons: {
    "Edit": function() { $("#edit_person_<%= @person.id %>").submit() },
  },
  open: function() {
    $("#person-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>")
  },
});
```

This will render a partial _form.html.erb into the dialog box.

Note: you're going to need to setup jQueryUI style as well for the dialog to render nice and pretty.

Comment: Hi, just came across this example. Thanks a lot as at least it make the modal window appear on the screen. However... it appears from the beginning. So as soon as I go into my index view it pops up, not when I click on the remote link. I'm sure it was not supposed to work like that. maybe you have suggestions?

Comment: Jinyoung - I am trying to implement a form in a dialog box using your guidance. Am I doing something obviously wrong? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953135/trying-to-make-a-form-in-a-jquery-dialog-modal-form-work-what-am-i-missing)  Thanks

Comment: Hi thatdankent, I think I might have found the bug and posted it in your questions. Good luck.

Comment: @ JinyoungKim I'm working on rendering a modal on demand via javascript and I see your code here, would my ajax controller methods be any different from normal ajax to make the above work? And I'm confused by the ("#edit_person_<%= @person.id %>") string, is this some form of jQuery magic to submit the right model to the server?

Comment: ("#edit_person_<%= @person.id %>") is how you select that HTML form element in jQuery, so you can submit it. Check out what the <%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %> is going to render. That form is going to have the HTML id of something along the lines of "edit_person_4". Whatever that id is going to be, you need the "Edit" button to select that form $("#HTMLID") is how you select an element in the DOM via an id in jQuery.

Comment: Your answer worked almost like a charm to me, except for: How to treat errors in this solution? If validation fails, instead to "reload" edit on dialog, it goes to HTML rendering on edit. On update method, I've set format.js  { render "edit", :content_type => 'text/javascript' } but with no success