# Flash messages in rails 4 not showing (within partial, within modal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog, simple-form, flash-message

The problem in brief: I'm working on a rails 4 app (4.1.8) and I'm trying to get `flash[:notice]` and `flash[:alert]` to show up under a form.

Two controllers: `landingpage_controller` and `contacts_controller`. The `landingpage_controller` serves a static landingpage through its `show` action and the `contacts_controller` has `new` and `create` actions, to store the contacts in a db table.

On the static landingpage, a modal with `id="contact-modal"` contains a partial with a simple_form_for @contact (see below). Upon submittal of the form, a db-entry is *not* created if the fields are not all filled out and a db-entry *is* created if the fields are filled out. *However, no flash messages are displayed.*

**Wanted output:**

Ideally the partial would re-load without leaving/closing the modal, with either: a success message and an empty form or a alert message and the form as it was upon submittal. **How do I do this?**

The controller: `app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb`

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    render layout: "contact"
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        flash[:notice] = "Success"
        format.js
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Error"
        format.js
      end
    end
  end


  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:email, :structure, :message_content)
  end

end
```

The form: `app/views/contacts/_new.html.haml`

```
= simple_form_for @contact, html: { id: "contact-form"} do |c|
  = c.input :email
  = c.input :structure
  = c.input :message_content
  = c.button :submit

.messages-container
  = if flash[:notice]
    %p
      = flash[:notice]
  = if flash[:alert]
    %p
      = flash[:alert]
```

Routes:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

I'm aware that a partial reload probably involves AJAX. I've read several StackOverflow questions on this but have not been able to figure it out. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204705/rails-partial-in-modal-render-partial-from-different-model), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery) and these two blog-posts: [jetthoughts](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html), [ericlondon](http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html).

Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. views, that start with underscore are called partials and are not full actions, but just parts of reusable view code (you don't redirect to them, instead you use `render` since you usually don't want a full page reload.

1.1 Rename your `_new.html.haml` to `_form.html.haml`

2.1 Create a new view `new.html.erb`*(I guess you have that already, otherwise your `new` action might not work properly)* with content `= render 'form'`

From what I understand you don't want the modal to close, just to render a form after successful submission or if there is an error.

In that case:

1.create a `create.js.erb` file in your views/contacts folder
create.js.erb

```
$("#your_modal_id").html("<%= j( render 'form') %>")
```

2. change your `create` action

```
        def create
          @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
          respond_to do |format|
            if @contact.save
              flash[:notice] = "Success"
              format.js
            else
              flash[:alert] = "Error"
              format.js
            end       
          end
        end
```

3. to your form add `remote: true`

WARNING: This will leave your form filled in even if it is successful.

More about this topic see:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

Hope it helps, and I hope I didn't forget anything

Comment: Its a step further but I get an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error at the respond_to block. I thought the problem was in telling rails to use js (since it did work if it's html) so I tried to explicitly define it in the post route `defaults: { format: 'js' }`. Didn't work however

Comment: Did you add  `remote: true` to your form?

Comment: yes, in this manner: `= simple_form_for(@contact, html: { id: "contact-form"}, remote: true) do |c|` .. with and without brackets

Comment: Could you try the updated create action in my answer, and if that doesn't work than provide the full error and stack trace?

Comment: This is the terminal error trace http://pastebin.com/wCb0nL3t.  `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` stands out?

Comment: CSRF token verification is a different issue. I tried to replicate this part of your app, but everything seems to be working with the code I provided. Could you please update your question with the full controller code?

Comment: I cannot see any problem in your code. Hopefully someone else can answer, but if not I will make a simple demo application and share git repository so you can compare it and see what's not working.

Comment: For the CSRF token, be sure that you have this line in your layout file: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Comment: That line is present. Still haven't figured the problem out through, will make time coming week to see if I experience the same problem in a new environment